# Is it possible to set permissions on variable groups via the REST API?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I was curious if anyone knows how to set permissions (add/remove groups) to variable groups via the REST API.  I know there is the security namespace, however it requires a resource guid and I am not sure how to get that for a specific variable group?

Comment: any updates for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reverse engineer who to do this.  If anyone is curious on how it works feel free to talk a look at the powershell library for Azure DevOps I have put together -- https://github.com/ravensorb/Posh-AzureDevOps

Answer (score 2):

You want security *namespace* "Library" ( you need to [convert](https://dev.to/melezhik/permissions-calculator-for-azure-devops-security-model-pll) it to proper namespace_id ) and with *token* "Library/$project_id/VariableGroup/$variable_group_id"

`POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/accesscontrollists/{securityNamespaceId}?api-version=5.1`

For ACL management REST API see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access%20control%20lists/set%20access%20control%20lists?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Example request:

```
"value": [
    {
      "inheritPermissions": true,
      "token": "Library/$project_id/VariableGroup/$variable_group_id",
      "acesDictionary": {
        "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;S-1-9-1551374245-1204400969-2402986413-2179408616-0-0-0-0-1": {
          "descriptor": "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Identity;S-1-9-1551374245-1204400969-2402986413-2179408616-0-0-0-0-1",
          "allow": 31,
          "deny": 0
        }
      }
    }
]
```

Warning1 - At the moment the Microsoft doc on that topic is quite incomplete ( see, for example my [comment](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/6043#issuecomment-548383028) on github issue asking for clarification of variables groups authentication mechanism ).

Warning2 - Be careful with ACL changing requests for ALL variable groups in project  ( e.g. token=`Library/$project_id/` ), because you might end up with removing permissions from all users on your Ado project and it's could be hard to change it back.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid it is not possible to set variable groups permission via api.

There is only group id we can get from variable group api below, no resource id in the response.

```
 https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

When i tried fetching the http request trace with `F12` chrome. There is a value at the end of request url looks like the source id. And it is the project id combined with the variable group id. Donot know if this is resource guid you were looking for.

https://dev.azure.com//_apis/securityroles/scopes/distributedtask.variablegroup/roleassignments/resources/`39e13f04-cb4e-4fa8-b2f1-0ee8f4fc82c5%241`

Comment: @Shawn That is great it helped, You can mark your new post as [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)